# Launcher not auto-hiding while using Writer

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

Despite of setting the launcher bar to auto-hide mode, it stops auto-hiding after a while when I'm using Writer. What can an Ubuntu rookie like me do to solve this VERY annoying matter?

Answer (score 1):

One easy remedy is to drag an arbitrary icon (e.g. from the desktop) onto the launcher -- no need to drop it -- and the launcher seems to remember to hide itself ;)